# Joomla admin page login error after upgrade from 3.2 to 3.2.1

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

After upgrading my joomla version from 3.2 to 3.2.1, I am unable to login to the administrator account. When I try it is throwing invalid user or no user error. Please help.

Comment: What PHP version are you running? Ans when I say version, I mean the **exact** version. In Joomla 3.2, the `bcrypt` method for passwords was introduced as it's more secure, however people with PHP versions lower than 5.3.6 or 5.3.10 (can't remember which one) has problems as it's didn't support this new method. Due to this, it was removed in Joomla 3.2.1

Comment: why don't you try to recover the credentials ? Using forgot password link ?

Comment: @Lodder My PHP version is 4.3.17. I solved the problem by resetting the password in the database as described in the answer below.

Comment: @Apurv For admin account we can't recover password directly. We will get error message.

Comment: PHP 4.3? Serious? Why on earth are you still running 4.3? The minimum PHP version for Joomla 3.x is 5.3 so start upgrading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **reset your admin password** by these **following steps** :

--> Open **PHPMyAdmin**.

--> **Search #__users** table and **open it**.

--> **Find** your **admin** user **with email or "User Name"**.

--> Click on **Edit**.

--> Select **MD5 in "password's " data type** and **enter your new password in value field of password**.

--> **Save it**.

--> **Try to Log-in**, this will works.

Comment: You can't just simply type in a new password as they are encrypted using md5 + salt upon registration.

Comment: Please read my answer correctly, i have mentioned to select MD5 while you are going to change password.

Comment: Yes, but you are missing the essential part which is the **salt**. To enter a new password, you would have to use an online md5 + salt generator or copy and paste from a new Joomla installation, neither of which you have mentioned